# Problem with isset and $_POST

Tags: plugins, php

I have another question. Why I cant get into this 'isset' $_POST["zapisz"] in this code ? What is wrong ?

```
    function ow_display_user() {
    ?>
    <pre style="text-align: left;">
    <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') var_dump($_POST); ?>
    </pre>
    <? 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT adres FROM wp_ow_adres;");
    ?>
<form name="one" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="Adres">Adres zamieszkania</label></th>
                <td><select id="adres" name="adres">
                        <option value="">Wybierz swój adres</option>
                        <?php 
                        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            echo '<option>'.$result->adres.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Wybierz" />

                <td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php 
$adres = $_POST["adres"];

if (isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $spr_liczbe_wodo = $wpdb->get_var("select liczba_wodomierzy from wp_ow_adres where adres='$adres'");

    if ($spr_liczbe_wodo == 4) {
    ?>
        <form name="two" method="post" action="http://localhost.local/">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Adres zamieszkania:</td>
        <td><?php $adres?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Woda ciepła (kuchnia):</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="woda_ciepla_kuchnia" name="woda" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="zapisz" name="zapisz" value="Zapisz" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
    <?

        if(isset($_POST['zapisz']))
        {
        $woda_ciepla_kuchnia=1;
        $data_odczytu = '0013-00-00 22:00:00';

                $data = array(
                'id' => '',
                'adres' => 'dasd',
                'data_odczytu' => $data_odczytu,
                'woda_ciepla_kuchnia' => 1,

                );

                $wpdb->insert(wp_ow_odczyty, (array)$data);

                            }
                            }

    }

}
```

Comment: check you code, their is a semicolon in it after second `if` close.this should not be their.

Comment: I change $wpdb->insert(wp_ow_odczyty, (array)$data);

                            }
                            }; to

$wpdb->insert(wp_ow_odczyty, (array)$data);

                            }
                            }
correct ?

Comment: yes this syntax is correct

Comment: Still the same issue. Any idea ?

Comment: Where are you setting `ok` and 'adres' in form? You are checking `isset($_POST['ok'])`, `$_POST["adres"]`,  are you sure this is the proper code? Also, there is no need to use that much echo statements to print the form code, just close `php` tag after `if ($spr_liczbe_wodo == 4) { ?>` and start php tag after `</form> <?php` and write simple html in between

Comment: @sven now you have all code from this function.

Comment: I've made a small change and formatting to your code `http://codepad.org/7m6IF4jh`, `$adres = $_POST["adres"];` should be inside `if (isset($_POST['ok'])){`, otherwise it would generate a warning, also you have specified a action in your second form. When you submit your first form do you get your second form echoed ? please remove the action from second form and try running code.

Also this is a very inconsistent approach you should use a better one

Comment: Can you paste a code for me ? Do you want to remove the second form ?

Comment: The codepad link have it http://codepad.org/7m6IF4jh, when you submit your first form, do you get the second form? and you are making the function call each time page loads??

Or maybe you can explain what are you doing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12210/discussion-between-sven-and-przemyslaw-suszek)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the second form `</form>` make a small change close the first two if's, and remove the two `}` from end of function

```
     </form><?php
     }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['zapisz'])) {
    $woda_ciepla_kuchnia=1;
    $data_odczytu = '0013-00-00 22:00:00';

    $data = array(
      'id' => '',
      'adres' => 'dasd',
      'data_odczytu' => $data_odczytu,
      'woda_ciepla_kuchnia' => 1,
    );
    $wpdb->insert(wp_ow_odczyty, (array)$data);
   }
 }
```

Comment: why  do you use `(array)$data` if you are already have variable with type `array` ?

Comment: It's just I didn't edited the rest of code in question, (array) it is not really required :)